# oracle adf how to disable selected rows by click on bottun?

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I have oracle adf and jdeveloper.

I have a table(multiselection) in jsf page with  .
I want to disable selected rows by cliching a button.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: This should work, depending on the version you are using. http://www.learnoracleadf.com/2014/05/select-and-unselect-all-rows-in-adf.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to disable selection of rows in a table. Your question is not very clear.

Create a bean and an attribute inside it which will handle the table selection. This can have the values "single", "none" etc. Read more about it here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_table.html

Drag and drop a button, double click it to create the code in the backing bean. Write logic in the button such that it will change the value of the previously defined variable.

Point the rowSelection attribute of the table in your page to the value in the bean.

```
public class MyBean {

    private String rowSelection="multiple"

    public String getRowSelection{
        return this.rowSelection;
    }

    public void setRowSelection(String rowSelection){
        this.rowSelection=rowSelection;
    }

    public String DisableRowSelection {
        this.rowSelection="none";
        return null;
    }

    public String EnableRowSelection {
        this.rowSelection="multiple";
        return null;
    }
}
```

The table:

```
<af:table value="#{bindings.myViewObject.collectionModel}" ...//other attributes
  rowSelection="#{myBean.rowSelection}" ...//other attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a transient attribute to your ViewObject called for example **IsSelected** then iterate through your view Object and set  **IsSelected** attributte to  **Y**  for all selected rows .

and set inline-style for all columns

```
 inlineStyle="#{row.IsSelected eq 'Y' ?'background-color:white;' : '' }"
```